# What is the life story of Sri Lakulisha?

Tags: tradition, guru, life, pashupata-shaivism

[Sri Lakulisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakulisha) was the famous propagator of pAshupata tradition of Shaivism. He is considered as an incarnation of Shiva.

What is his life story?

What are his main teachings?

Are there any miracles associated with him?

Comment: Shiva Purana provides two lines regarding his birth. If you are ok, i can post it as partial answer.

Comment: @TheDestroyer you can use other sources like biographies or pasupata scriptures.